# Moving to France, American resident (Finnish Citizen who has never lived there)

Tags: france, eu, health-insurance, health, finland

I know I can technically move to France, but since I have not been living in the EU- is there anything I need to be aware of? For example, how to register as a resident, how to obtain public health insurance or other state benefits in case I do not get a job right away.

Comment: The question is a bit broad, you might want to focus it on one aspect (say health insurance) and ask other follow-up questions as necessary.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to register in any way in France. In general, under EU law, you can stay in France under one of two regimes:

- As a worker, in which case you would automatically be covered by the French mandatory health insurance system
- As a non-economically active person, in which case you need to have health insurance and sufficient financial means not to rely on welfare benefits

There is however no unconditional right to reside in France if you have no job and no resources so it might not be possible to obtain health insurance if you can't find work.

Once you have stayed in France for five years either as a worker or as a non-economically active person, you would become a permanent resident, with full access to French state benefits and health insurance (including the “couverture maladie universelle” for people who don't have any other coverage).

If you are *looking* for work, you can stay in France but not get state benefits or free health insurance. EU citizens who come from their another country can transfer unemployment benefits and are sometimes covered by that country's health insurance system but if you have never lived and worked in Finland I don't think you could benefit from that. You would in any case need a Finnish “European Health Insurance Card”. Otherwise, I think you need private health insurance with equivalent coverage.

Full explanation (in French) on [securite-sociale.fr](http://www.securite-sociale.fr/Affiliation-a-la-CMU-pour-les-ressortissants-europeens-inactifs-etudiants-ou-demandeurs-d) or [cleiss.fr](http://www.cleiss.fr/particuliers/venir_resider_en_france_eee_cmu.html)